# Orbits and stabilizersof S4

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Now I've read the theory but these things are still too abstract for me. One of the assignments in my book goes as follows:  Let $V_4 ⊂ S_4$ given is an integer $n > 1$ Let $V_4$ act on $X$ = {$1, 2, 3, 4$}$^n$ through $σ$ ◦ ($i_1$, . . . , $i_n$) = σ($i_1$), . . . , σ($i_n$)

1. Prove that all elements in X have a trivial stabilizer. 
2. How many orbits are there?

If someone could help me answer these I would at least have something to start off with.

Comment: What do you mean by  "Let $V_4\subset S_4$ given is an integer $n>1$" ?

Answer (score 2):

As a subgroup of $S_4$, $V_4$ is normally taken to be

$$V_4=\{\text{id},(1,2)(3,4),(1,3)(2,4),(1,4)(2,3)\}\;.$$

Let’s look at the case $n=3$ as an example. $X=\{1,2,3,4\}^3$ is the set of ordered triples $\langle i_1,i_2,i_3\rangle$ such that $i_1,i_2,i_3\in\{1,2,3,4\}$. If $\sigma\in V_4$, then

$$\sigma\cdot\langle i_1,i_2,i_3\rangle=\langle\sigma(i_1),\sigma(i_2),\sigma(i_3)\rangle\;.$$

For instance,

$$\begin{align*}
&\text{id}\cdot\langle 1,4,2\rangle=\langle\text{id}(1),\text{id}(4),\text{id}(2)\rangle=\langle 1,4,2\rangle\;,\\
&(1,2)(3,4)\cdot\langle 1,4,2\rangle=\langle[(1,2)(3,4)](1),[(1,2)(3,4)](4),[(1,2)(3,4)](2)\rangle=\langle 2,3,1\rangle\;,\\
&(1,3)(2,4)\cdot\langle 1,4,2\rangle=\langle[(1,3)(2,4)](1),[(1,3)(2,4)](4),[(1,3)(2,4)](2)\rangle=\langle 3,2,4\rangle\;,\text{ and}\\
&(1,4)(2,3)\cdot\langle 1,4,2\rangle=\langle[(1,4)(2,3)](1),[(1,4)(2,3)](4),[(1,4)(2,3)](2)\rangle=\langle 4,1,3\rangle\;.\\
\end{align*}$$

The orbit of $\langle 1,4,2\rangle$ is therefore

$$\{\sigma\cdot\langle 1,4,2\rangle:\sigma\in V_4\}=\{\langle 1,4,2\rangle,\langle 2,3,1\rangle,\langle 3,2,4\rangle,\langle 4,1,3\rangle\}\;.$$

The only element of $V_4$ that acts trivially on $\langle 1,4,2\rangle$, i.e., that sends $\langle 1,4,2\rangle$ to itself, is $\text{id}$, the identity permutation. Thus, the stabilizer of $\langle 1,4,2\rangle$ is $\{\text{id}\}$, which is indeed trivial.

Your first exercise is to show that no matter what integer $n>1$ we take, and no matter which $n$-tuple $\langle i_1,\ldots,i_n\rangle$ of integers from the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$ we take, the only member of $V_4$ that sends $\langle i_1,\ldots,i_n\rangle$ to itself is the identity permutation. In other words, you need to show that if $\sigma$ is any one of the other three members of $V_4$, there is always at least one $k$ such that $\sigma(i_k)\ne i_k$. In fact you can prove a much stronger statement: if $\sigma$ is one of the other three members of $V_4$, then $\sigma(i_k)\ne i_k$ for **all** $k=1,\ldots,n$.

For the second question, prove (or, if you’ve already done so, use the fact) that the orbits of the action form a partition of $X$. Using the first question, it’s not hard to see how big each orbit is, and it’s easy to express $|X|$ in terms of $n$; put the two together properly, and you’ll get the number of orbits.